# Como pasar Query hecha en C# a SQLSever

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy intentando pasar una Query que tengo hecha en **C#** lo cual estoy trabajando en un proyecto hecho en ASP.NET, quiero pasarla a SQLServer, esto con el fin de saber el tiempo que demora en devolverme el resultado de la consulta y así poder optimizarla.

**Query hecha en C#**

```
public static TicketDetailResult GetTicketDetails(long ticketId)
        {
            var result = new TicketDetailResult();
            try
            {
                using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
                {
                    var tickets = from tblTicket in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                        join tblRecord in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecord.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                        join tblServices in db.TK_CT_SERVICES on tblRecord.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID equals tblServices
                            .TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
                        join tblStatus in db.TK_CT_STATUS on tblRecord.TK_CT_STATUS_ID equals tblStatus.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
                        join tblCategories in db.TK_CT_CATEGORIES on tblRecord.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID equals tblCategories
                            .TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID
                        where tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID==ticketId && tblRecord.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID == (
                                  from tblTicketAux in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                                  join tblRecordAux in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals
                                      tblRecordAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                                  where tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID == tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                                  select tblRecordAux.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
                              ).Max()
select new TicketDetailsAux()
                        {
                            Sheet = tblTicket.FOLIO,
                            TicketId=tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID,
                            Title = tblTicket.TITLE,
                            ContentTicket = tblTicket.CONTENT,
                            CustomerId=tblTicket.CUSTOMER_ID,
                            CustomerFullName = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,
                            CustomerEmail = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
                            CustomerExtension = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_EXTENSION,
                            CustomerArea = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_AREA,
                            CustomerLocation = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_LOCATION,
                            Content = tblRecord.CONTENT,
                            Status = tblStatus.TK_CT_STATUS_ID,
                            ServiceId = tblServices.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID,
                            PrioritiesId = tblRecord.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID,
                            CategoryId = tblRecord.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID,
                            EmployeeId = tblRecord.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID,
                            Note=tblRecord.NOTE,
                            Origin= tblTicket.ORIGIN,
                        };
```

**Consulta hecha en SQLServer**

```
    select TK_HD_TICKETS.FOLIO, TK_HD_TICKETS.TITLE, TK_HD_TICKETS.CONTENT, TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_ID, 
TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME, TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_EMAIL, TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_EXTENSION,
TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_AREA, TK_HD_TICKETS.CUSTOMER_LOCATION, TK_DT_RECORDS.CONTENT,
TK_CT_STATUS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID, TK_CT_SERVICES.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID,
TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID, TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID, TK_DT_RECORDS.NOTE, TK_HD_TICKETS.ORIGIN FROM TK_HD_TICKETS JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
    JOIN TK_CT_SERVICES ON TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID = TK_CT_SERVICES.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
    JOIN TK_CT_STATUS ON TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = TK_CT_STATUS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
    JOIN TK_CT_CATEGORIES ON TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID = TK_CT_CATEGORIES.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID
    WHERE ((TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = '15' AND TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID IN 
    (SELECT * FROM TK_HD_TICKETS 
    JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID 
    WHERE (TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID))));
```

El motivo de mi pregunta es que me esta generando el siguiente error al ejecutar la consulta en **SQLServer** (version 2014)

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Quiero saber si estoy ejecutando bien la consulta en **SQLServer** o me hace falta corregir algo para solucionar el error que indique anteriormente

Comment: Cuando tienes muchos Joins y la data es sólo de lectura, se hace más fácil crear una Vista en SQL Server, hacer un mapping mediante Entity Framework y trabajarlo como si fuera una tabla más.

Comment: SELECT * FROM TK_HD_TICKETS en esta parte te traeria muchos datos no? y solo debe de traer un campo

Comment: @EdgarVazquez con respecto a tu comentario ya agregue los campos dentro del SELECT que seria los que deseo mostrar aun así me sigue generando el error

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta  y poner tu consulta y de ser posible tus tablas con unos datos para observar lo que esta pasando

Comment: @EdgarVazquez la consulta ya esta publicada debajo de consulta hecha en SQLServer y lo que me muestra es mensaje de error _Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS._

Comment: Al usar un IN, El select dentro del mismo no puede devolver mas de un campo. Si asi fuera, como hace la DB para saber con cual campo comparar el que vos queres?

Comment: y estas confundiendo el in de linq con el in de sql, que no tienen nada que ver uno con otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que ya estás haciendo una subconsulta relacionada, creo que sería una mejor alternativa el usar EXISTS en vez de IN. Así no necesitas usar una sola columna y puedes comparar varias al mismo tiempo.

Aún mejor sería dar formato a tu código para que sea legible.

```
SELECT TI.FOLIO,
    TI.TITLE,
    TI.CONTENT,
    TI.CUSTOMER_ID,
    TI.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,
    TI.CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
    TI.CUSTOMER_EXTENSION,
    TI.CUSTOMER_AREA,
    TI.CUSTOMER_LOCATION,
    RE.CONTENT,
    ST.TK_CT_STATUS_ID,
    SE.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID,
    RE.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID,
    RE.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID,
    RE.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID,
    RE.NOTE,
    TI.ORIGIN
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS    TI
JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS    RE ON TI.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = RE.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
JOIN TK_CT_SERVICES   SE ON RE.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID = SE.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
JOIN TK_CT_STATUS     ST ON RE.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = ST.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
JOIN TK_CT_CATEGORIES CA ON RE.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID = CA.TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID
WHERE TI.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = '15'
AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM TK_HD_TICKETS ITI
                JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS IRE ON ITI.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = IRE.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                WHERE TI.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = ITI.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                AND   RE.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = IRE.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
            );
```